# Finding the first new commit of all branches?

Tags: git

I have already constructed the git command:

`git log --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --pretty=format:"%ad, %an, %s" master..[branch name] | tail -1`.

This allows me to checkout the branch `[branch name]`, then running this command will get me the first commit of the checked out branch that is not on on `master`. While this is great, it is a bit time consuming as I need to checkout the branch first and customise the command.

To avoid this headache, is there a single command that I can run to find the first new commit details on all remote branches of a specific git repo?

Comment: Create an alias with the branch name as a parameter. That being said, it's worth noting that nothing in your command requires the branch to be checked out. Try `git config alias.something '!f() { git log --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --pretty=format:"%ad, %an, %s" master.."$1" | tail -1; }; f'` Laucnhing the command without any parameter will use `HEAD` by default.

Comment: @millie : your command works, and you don't need to checkout a branch to run it. What you may need is to use the name of the *remote* branch (e.g : `origin/that/feature` instead of `that/feature`) if you don't want to go through the hassle of creating a local branch. I think RomainValeri gave a good answer on how to turn your command into a convenient alias, if you are looking for something more can you please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'd recommend tweaking the wording of this question to make it clearer. Maybe the title could be, "Finding the first **new** commit of all branches?" And in the question something like, "will get me the first *new* commit of the checked out branch, compared to `master`."

Comment: I don't have an answer, just terminology that may help. The most recent commit in common on two branches is called the "merge base". This isn't quite the commit you are trying to find, but googling more about this concept my help you in that direction.

Comment: In your last paragraph, you're asking how to do your operation all all remote branches. You can do it with a bash loop over all branches: `for branch in $(git branch --format='%(refname:short)' -a); do echo branch $branch; <insert your command here>; done`.

Comment: Also, it might help to understand how git works to clarify your question. A branch is just a reference to a single commit. Talking about "the first new commit on a branch" doesn't technically mean what you think it means. In some sense, a branch "contains" all of the commits from the commit it references back to the very first commit in the history of the repo. Understanding this concept can help us understand why it's not so easy to do exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last paragraph, you're asking how to do your operation on all remote branches, and I think that's the core of your question, so that's what I'm answering here.

You can do it with a bash loop over all branches:

```bash
for branch in $(git branch --format='%(refname:short)' -a | grep origin/); do
    echo branch $branch
    git log --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --pretty=format:"%ad, %an, %s" master.."$branch" | tail -1
done
```

Notes:

- I put a `| grep origin/` in that for loop, to list only branches on origin, but you can remove that part to see all branches from anywhere.
- The `--format='%(refname:short)'` option is a good one for scripting the output of `git branch`, because it prints just the branch name and nothing else.
- The `git log` command in the middle is exactly your command, with `"$branch"` plugged in at the right place.